# Hide from windows 10 guest OS that it is running as VM in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization

I have a software provided by online tutorials that runs fine when running from windows 10 natively. However I have now started using Linux mint as my primary OS along with win 10 in dual boot. So I also installed win 10 in VirtualBox under Linux mint. However the software refuses to run saying " I cannot run in VM. Please run me in direct boot". 
How can I make the software believe it is running natively? Is there any virtualbox config or settings change achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pure guess, but it could be looking at something like the graphics driver - which will be clearly one from a VM.

Example below from a different VM, Windows 10 running inside Parallels on Mac, but shows the issue...

[image]

There is no way to 'hide' that info from any probe.

I have seen similar issues even running one macOS VM inside macOS - which ought to raise no licensing issues at all, yet some things can still be blocked. My guess is it could be to prevent you gaining multiple copies in various different states by simply duplicating the VM at will.